# UI Form Component get weird compile error

Tags: magento2, adminhtml

I'm trying to import an UI Component in Adminhtml but i get an error like this:

```
Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->createObject('\n    \xC2\xA0\xC2\xA0\xC2\xA0\xC2\xA0\xC2\xA0...', Array)

#1 /home/alberto.freguco/www/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(57): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Compiled->create('\n    \xC2\xA0\xC2\xA0\xC2\xA0\xC2\xA0\xC2\xA0...', Array)
#2 /home/alberto.freguco/www/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/UiComponent/Argument/Interpreter/ConfigurableObject.php(60): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->create('\n    \xC2\xA0\xC2\xA0\xC2\xA0\xC2\xA0\xC2\xA0...', Array)
```

I don't understand why i get **\xC2\xA0\xC2\xA0\xC2\xA0\xC2\xA0\xC2\xA0...** encoding stuff.

Has anyone here the some problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing this happens only for a perticular UI component xml. If you open that XML in browser, does it open correctly. At the top of your XML is there a encoding attribute which says utf8